# Unable to resolve service for type 'IRepositoryPMS.IProductRepository' while attempting to activate 'Controllers.HomeController'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to register my repositories in a .NET Core environment. However, I am not able to resolve my repositories in the controller.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiPbx.png) is the error that I am dealing with is

I have tried to add repository and IRepository in service. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZuz0.png) is the registration method.

also, I added on controller constructor. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMbI.png) is here.

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages / code. Copy them into your post and format them appropriately.

Comment: Probably the issue is related to your DI container. Please try to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and follow the instruction explained. By the way, you should include your codes in your question instead of adding screen shots.

Comment: Could you please share your `IProductRepository` and `ProductRepository` ?And please share the code instead of sharing the screenshot.